# AEM dynamic components parbase

Tags: aem

I have components that are generated dynamically after they are added to the page. These components are generated on the fly and in some instances are floating elements. This makes it very dificult for parsys to draw correctly. All the time the parsys (parbase - css class name) has a height of 0. I can fix that by changing the default property of parbase from overflow="visible" to overflow="auto". However I want to know if anyone else has run into this issue and what is the best method to do this implementation when you are only on edit mode but ignore it on any other view.

Comment: We've run into the issue several times. The only solution I know is not to use float for your components.

Comment: is there a reason you can't just render them as floats in preview/publish mode and have them flow normally in edit mode?

Answer (score 0):

So you have a few options.
First, you can check the WCMMode in the page header and if the mode is EDIT then you can load an "editmode.css" after your main CSS has loaded.  This is where I put overrides to handle drawing issues like what you encountered.

This keeps it all in one place, and in any mode other than edit that css will never load.

The second option is to allow these items to flow normally in Edit mode and disable floats, as suggested above.  Depending on how editing works, one or the other might be superior.